# Is this string-comparison function safe against timing attacks?

Tags: javascript, security

Here's a JavaScript function that check the equality of `input` and `secret` strings, trying to do that without leaking information about `secret`:

```
function timeSafeEqual(input, secret) {
    let equal = input.length === secret.length

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; ++i) {
        const ofInput = input[i]
        const ofSecret = secret[i]

        if (ofInput !== ofSecret) {
            equal = false
        }
    }

    return equal
}
```

The function seems to always run in `O(input.length)` time. Would you consider it to be timing-safe? This code runs on Node.js

Maybhe the time to compare `undefined` `string` values might be different than the time to compare `string` and `string` in V8?

Comment: So if `input` has a length of `10` and `secret` has a length of `5`, what will `secret[5]` return? Honest question, I don't know TypeScript too well and other languages will throw an exception for out of bounds access, likely giving away the actual length of the secret.

Comment: @Marvin In JavaScript it will return `undefined`

Comment: Where are you running this Javascript (previously Typescript) code?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The code runs on Node.js. I've edited the question

Comment: You've got a clear question, and the environment to test it. Did you do that? To prevent timing attacks you could simply add a random short delay in this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it safe?

No.

---

## bug

```
    let equal = input.length === secret.length
```

In the [happy path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happy_path)
we assign True and life is good.

When we assign False, then de-referencing `input[i]` and `secret[i]` is trouble.
Minimally, the attempted de-reference will consume a perceptibly
different amount of delay.
If we get an `undefined` back, then XORing it will be trouble.

---

Assume we assigned `equal = True` above.

## timing of a conditional

```
        if (ofInput !== ofSecret) {
            equal = false
        }
```

This is just Bad.

We perform N comparisons, so that much is fine,
there's no early exit.

But for M out of N mis-matches,
we're performing an extra M assignments
which an adversary armed with a stopwatch can observe.
Total failure.

### fix

Compute and store N xor's.
In the case that the strings are equal,
we store N zeros.

Sum the xor results and return that.
Non-zero means the strings don't match.

Consider hashing both strings initially, then compare the hashes.
One advantage is you're guaranteed to be comparing hashes
of identical length.
Another is that you have flexibility to pre-hash
on a different host or at a previous time.

---

## random jitter

Your adversary's ability to observe what's happening
is impacted by random noisy delays caused by router queues
and host scheduler queues.

Roll a random number and sleep that long before returning a boolean result.
That way the adversary has less effective signalling bandwidth
for his observations, so effective attacks will take much longer.

Comment: Indeed, all great points, thank you! I ended up using this algorithm: 1. Store secret in memory buffer. 2. Create `badSecret` buffer by flipping all bits of secret. 3. Set `bufferToCompare = input.length === secret.length ? input : badSecret`. 4. Xor `bufferToCompare` and `secret`, sum, and check if result is 0